# Get subdomain from TCP socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, dns, subdomain

I am writing a server application that accepts TCP connections from different programs/protocols but I need to pass additional information to my server. I was thinking of passing this information through the subdomain being used. In other words, when connecting to my server, using an address such as `somedata.example.com` where `somedata` will be the extra information I need and my DNS will point `*.example.com` to my server. Would it be possible to fetch the domain/subdomain that the client used to connect to my server?

Code samples are welcome and in Go would be even better.

Thank you.

Comment: Hostnames and subdomains are communicated in the http protocol. They are not necessarily communicated in arbitrary tcp streams.

Comment: What protocols specifically are you using? Are you using tls? An SNI handshake might have the info you need.

Comment: My server would be working at the TCP socket level. Perhaps you can elaborate on how to fetch this data from the SNI handshake for anyone else that could be interested and does not have the same restrictions I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TCP connection is conceptually just a stream of bytes in each direction. There is no single way that a hostname with subdomain would be communicated. Most protocols have their own way of communicating that if they need it. Examples:

- An http request has a `HOST` header.
- When initiating a tls connection, the handshake usually includes the desired host name.

If you are using some standard protocol, you should use their built-in metadata facilities.

If you are building your own custom binary protocol (I wouldn't if I could avoid it), you may consider adding some header info in some format. Perhaps a standardized header of `length|desired-service-name|other-data` would be sufficient. If the client sends something like that at the start of a new connection, the server can read it, and dispatch the connection appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid this was going to be the case.